# Wiki + tags + search by tags

Tags: cms, search, wiki, tags

I need a MediaWiki-like user-editable CMS that supports pages tagging. The same tag system as in the Wordpress. And I also need a search-by-tags page which lists all unique tags and allows visitor to search content by checkboxing the tags of his needs.

Thus visitors should be able to edit pages, add tags and search by tags.

What can you recommend? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Mediawiki, which is very Mediawiki-like, and has supported tags for years.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't find any search-by-tag solution for Mediawiki which I described. And by tags support, do you mean this https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Miscellaneous ?

Comment: If you click on a tag in mediawiki, you get all the results for that tag.  If you need an external search, maybe you can google the wiki's site for the tag?  I don't think I've ever seen a system where you can enter tags but not retrieve what you tag

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please provide an example of what you do mean by a MediaWiki tag. It may look like I'm an idiot but I really can't find any sufficent information about a MediaWiki's tags and tag managing.

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Tiea54gmugpqpkc9 because mediawiki started way before tags, they are called categories.  And if you want to search for them explicitly there are extensions you can install